# Powershell SCCM client side application install

Tags: powershell, sccm

I am trying to write a script that can be ran on a client system to install an application from software center. I found this and modified it to run on a local machine. https://timmyit.com/2016/08/08/sccm-and-powershell-force-installuninstall-of-available-software-in-software-center-through-cimwmi-on-a-remote-client/

The problem is that in root/ccm/clientSDK:CCM_Application only gets populated with software that has been installed, as far as I can tell anyway. Is there a method that I can call to search the SCCM Catalog for the application I need? I have searched for an answer to this for a couple days now. The server is managed by a different team in the company so I only have access to client side. I am still new to both SCCM and Powershell.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the short answer is No, see below link to a similar question.

[CCM_Application User available software missing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53276451/ccm-application-user-available-software-missing/53285383#53285383)

Software deployed to Software Centre or to an "All Users" collection is not searchable via the sdk classes