# CCM_Application User available software missing

Tags: wmi, sccm

While querying the namespace root\ccm\clientsdk class ccm_application I've found that it'll contain objects for any triggered application installs and not user available applications.
Has anyone found a way around this?

Comment: I don't have experience with this but are you really checking with the correct user here? Is it possible that you check this with some admin who does not have the application deployed to?

Comment: I really don't think you understand or even read my question..

Answer (score 0):

From what you're saying I think this is by design with SCCM, but may be different in the more recent windows 10 versions.

What I've seen with it is that applications made available to a User collection don't seem to appear in the local client classes. This makes sense because the target of the deployment isn't the machine. Deployments made available to User Collections only seem to appear through the webservices used by the application Catalog if you have that setup.

Comment: Defiantly by design, looking at it you can worry the primary site server for the logged on user advertisements, just need to confirm if you can force an install

Comment: Why force an install of an available application? If it needs to be installed why not set it to required?

Comment: There could be scenarios where you'd want something to be available and then trigger it at a specific time. Few and far between though

Comment: You still can make a second deployment for the same thing and make it required. I mean I have seen lots of crazy scenarios with sccm that forced you to do stuff you shouldn't have to so I have no doubt there could be a plausible scenario for that (e.g. I have heard of people that need to mass trigger something but don't even have access to sccm because that is a different department). I was more like 50% curious what the motivation might be and 50% trying to hint that this might also maybe be a situation where there is normally a better solution